# Connecting Android Studio to Google Cloud

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-studio

I am trying to find tutorials on how to connect the Android Studio on Google Cloud, unfortunately I cant find any. I import php for the database and tried to create backend on Android studio using google endpoints then I dont know what's next. Can someone help me or give some links that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

this link may help you
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/
u can download source code and learn something new..